# IndexedDB in firefox

Tags: database, linux, firefox, indexeddb, linux-mint

I've encountered issues with using IndexedDB on Firefox in a Linux environment. I'm running Firefox 22.0 for Ubuntu.
When I `put` or `delete` objects from indexedDB I receive the following error:
A request was placed against a transaction which is currently not active, or which is finished. name: TransactionInactiveError

The above issue is encountered in both Firefox on Kubuntu and Linux Mint. However the same IndexeDB code runs successfully on both Chrome in Linux and Firefox in Windows.

Are there known indexedDB issues on Firefox for Linux?

Comment: I have fairly extensively used IndexedDB in Firefox 22 on Ubuntu. I haven't noticed the problems you described. You should try to make a minimal example and post the code here.

Comment: Try adding an oncomplete callback to your transaction and look if it gets called before making your call. Looking at the error you are trying to access a transaction that is already completed or aborted. Keep in mind that the indexedDB API only keeps the transactions open for a short timespan and transactions are autocommited

Comment: you should post some code.